# Get all dates between two dates with id

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table with sales like this:

```
Select Id, startdate, endate
From tabe

Output: 
1 '01-01-2022' '06-01-2022'
1 '02-01-2022' '05-01-2022'
1 '13-01-2022' '17-01-2022'
2 '01-01-2022' '02-01-2022' 
2 '01-01-2022' '03-01-2022'
Etc
```

So basically one id can be in different sales. What i need is this table format:

```
01-01-2022 1
02-01-2022 1
03-01-2022 1
04-01-2022 1
05-01-2022 1
06-01-2022 1
07-01-2022 1
13-01-2022 1
14-01-2022 1
15-01-2022 1
16-01-2022 1
17-01-2022 1
01-01-2022 2 
02-01-2022 2
03-01-2022 2

Etc.
```

I also can't create a new table for a calendar.
I have found a solution with unequal join (on date between startdate and enddate) i have a table with dates similar to calendar. But clickhouse can't join on inequalities.
Anybody has a thought how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  c1    AS id
, toDate (arrayJoin (range (toUInt32 (c2), toUInt32 (c3) + 1)))
        AS dt
FROM VALUES 
(
  (1, toDate ('2022-01-01'), toDate ('2022-01-06'))
, (1, toDate ('2022-01-02'), toDate ('2022-01-05'))
, (1, toDate ('2022-01-13'), toDate ('2022-01-17'))
, (2, toDate ('2022-01-01'), toDate ('2022-01-02'))
, (2, toDate ('2022-01-01'), toDate ('2022-01-03'))
)
```

| id | dt |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 |
| 1 | 2022-01-03 |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 |
| 1 | 2022-01-05 |
| 1 | 2022-01-06 |
| 1 | 2022-01-13 |
| 1 | 2022-01-14 |
| 1 | 2022-01-15 |
| 1 | 2022-01-16 |
| 1 | 2022-01-17 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 |
| 2 | 2022-01-03 |

[fiddle](https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/e536ac48-aec4-402b-aaac-d678ddae8a71)

Comment: nice solution, but i have many rows (about 200 000), so i cant use it

Comment: 200k rows is nothing for Clickhouse. Use `From tabe` with your real table instead of my `From values` apparently. I provided this test query just to show that it works.

Comment: This is the simpliest way to get the result desired. No unions. No joins. The number of rows in the table doesn't matter. So, what prevents you from using the query?

Comment: Instead of 'from values' i tried subquery and it worked! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `UNION`. Something like:

```
SELECT 
    startdate AS date,
    Id
FROM tabe
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    endate,
    Id
FROM tabe;
```

That will return:

```
┌─date───────┬─Id─┐
│ 03-01-2022 │  1 │
│ 04-01-2022 │  1 │
│ 14-01-2022 │  1 │
│ 02-01-2022 │  2 │
└────────────┴────┘
┌─date───────┬─Id─┐
│ 01-01-2022 │  1 │
│ 02-01-2022 │  1 │
│ 13-01-2022 │  1 │
│ 01-01-2022 │  2 │
└────────────┴────┘

8 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.002 sec.
```

Comment: But what if i have a gap between dates. For example 01-01-2022 and 10-01-2022 i need to show all dates between two of the following and id alongside.

Comment: I just looked at your input and generated your desired output. I'm not sure what you're asking - maybe you can share a better example.

Comment: I edited the question above and added some more examples